# Power Query Editor, queries pane sort order

Tags: powerbi

The Power Query Editor sorts the queries as they are loaded which can turn into a big mess.
How can one sort the queries alphabetically in the queries pane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that you can sort them alphabetically, but you can manually rearrange their order by clicking and dragging as well as put them into groups to organize them better.

To create a new group, right-click in the pane and select New Group... then give it an appropriate name and drag the queries you want in that group into that folder. Note that this automatically creates an "Other Queries" group where all queries not in an assigned group live.